# Why does my porch photo cell light cause bulb to only light half brightness?

Tags: electrical, low-voltage

I have a porch light that has a time/photoeye switch or it can be just on or off. It is on a 3 way switch and the are 2 other lights on the circuit that are not effected in this way.

When the sun goes down and the photoeye turns the lights on, the 2 garage lights turn on full brightness. The one on the porch will be on but very dim (LED bulb in now does same thing with CCFL).

The kicker is if I toggle the switch off/on all three lights will light up and be just fin, but sometime thru the night the porch light will go back to low brightness.

What might be causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: You have this tagged "low-voltage" are these actually low voltage DC lights or are they 120v AC powered?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this light "behavior " when the photocell is failing.

I know it makes no sense. (The cell should turn the circuit on or off.) However many of the outside lights around our condo have displayed this issue and photocell replacement was the cure.

If you cannot replace just the photocell, unfortunately you need to replace the entire fixture.